# .htaccess: rewrite condition and rewrite problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hosting, subdomain, shared

I am working on a CakePHP project in shared hosting with multiple subdomains. Due to problems with Cake's htaccess I had to move the main site into a subfolder, and write a new htaccess to redirect users to this folder (while leaving the subdomains requests intact). At the minute my htaccess file looks something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain/
    RewriteRule (.*) /domain/$1
</IfModule>
```

This works for requests with 'www' prepended to the url, but there are some issues with http: // domain.com requests. In IE & Chrome this address resolves itself to the 'www' url, but in Firefox & Safari, it shows the directory structure.

I need to figure out how to include the http: // domain.com requests in the rewrite conditions without affecting the other sub-domains.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. Adrian

Comment: Anyone? Please, I'm really stuck here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `%{HTTP_HOST}` rewrite condition as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain/ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /domain/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

- The `?` in `(www\.)?` says *zero* or *one* occurrence i.e. makes it optional.
- `[L]` marks it as last i.e. rewriting should stop at this rule.
- `[NC]` makes all matches case-insensitive.

Comment: It says I have to wait 5 hours to award the bounty

Comment: @AdrianTrainor Not a problem. I can wait. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the host match:

```
^(www\.)?domain\.com$
```